# Can I Exit my SSH Client After Starting an Update?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, update

I just ran `sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude dist-upgrade` through PuTTY (SSH Client) on my Laptop, which was directed at my fresh Ubuntu server. Unfortunately I just realized I need to be out of the house with my Laptop and I'm worried that by exiting my SSH client or having my Laptop disconnect form the internet that the server won't continue updating!

What will happen if I turn my Laptop off now that the server is updating?!

Comment: If it's already past the downloading packages part, don't stop it.  If it's still downloading you can hit ctrl-c and stop it then start it again with the suggestions below (it should resume whichever package was downloading)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using

```
nohup sudo aptitude dist-upgrade &
```

or (better) using screen, for this one better you study a bit [how to use it](http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/3/9/16838/14935).

You will be happy then with screen

Comment: +1 for screen. A command-line must-have.

Answer (score 5):

start screen

then in screen enter

apt-get update
apt-get upgrade

press ctrl-a d

and then you can disconnect

to reconnect to your session

screen -r

thats about it in a nutshell :)